# How to change default tabwidget color on loading in android?

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

Can anyone suggest me how to set background color for tab widget. i tried with some codes and with examples in the net but still i can't able to change the color. Advance thanks guys.
Below is my code:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("My Families", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabselect)),
                        Main.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("My Pictures", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabunselect)),
                    Second.class, null);
```

below in my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#2B78E4" />
</shape>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#999999" />
</shape>
```

Comment: You can check the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404907/how-to-set-background-color-tabhost

Comment: well on loading first time the background color doesn't change, only on clicking the tab it changes. What i want actually while loading on first which means oncreate() gets called i have to show tabs with different colors not black and merun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the following code in 
`for (int i = 0; i < tab.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
    tab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selected);
 tab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tab.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_unselected);`

in `onCreate()` method